# "Jail already initialized - returning"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Recently, I've been seeing this message in my console when I use something like

```
google.script.run.AppScriptFunctionThatIWrote();
```

Regardless of what it does or returns, it's always printing

> "Jail already initialized - returning"

to the browser console. At first, I thought it was an error but it prints even on valid code. 
It's only started appearing since yesterday which is what startled me. At this point, I'm mostly just curious. Anybody know what it is?

Comment: I have also started seeing this message in the last couple of days.

Comment: This issue has been posted about in the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111383280394705334200/posts/eqnW23ocRDz?cfem=1)

Comment: According to Ryan Roth in your link,

"Looks like this was a small logging bug. The Apps Script team is already aware of it -- it should be fixed soon."

Comment: According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765279 the problem was fixed.